# Wix - Hiding the MSI also hides the patches?

Tags: wix, patch, burn

Ran into this today on my patching work.

1. If I set both Burn and the MSI to visible..  Then both end up in the ARP list.  Patching works. Looks bad to the customer
2. If I set Burn to hide and the MSI visible... then patching works but uninstalling the msi works... but  fails to uninstall burn.
3. If I set Burn to visible and hide the MSI (MsiPackage Visible="no") patching works but does not show up in the ARP list - view installed updates.

I have learned that best practice is Burn needs to be in the ARP list and that is ok.

So the question or 2 is.

My patch is based off of the MSI. Is that right?

How do I get the patches to show up in the ARP list - view installed updates if the MSI is hidden?  (MsiPackage Visible="no")

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured it out at least for me.

I needed to use Burn to install the patch. I was just using msiexec.exe from the command line. Using this method put the patch into the ARP list.

This is the link to the article that worked for me.
http://howdididothatthingagain.blogspot.com/2013/06/authoring-patch-bundle.html

Thanks